# How to restart a loop in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a discord bot using [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I want to make a command to purge all messages inside a channel every 100 seconds. Here is my code:

```py
autodeletetime = -100
autodeletelasttime = 1



@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def autodelete(ctx):
        global autodeleterunning
        if autodeleterunning == False:
            autodeleterunning = True
            asgas = True
            while asgas:
                message = await ctx.send(f'All messages gonna be deleted in 100 seconds')
                await message.pin()
                for c in range(autodeletetime,autodeletelasttime):
                    okfe = abs(c)
                    await message.edit(content=f"All messages gonna be deleted in {okfe} seconds" )
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    if c == 0:
                    
                        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999)


                        await time.sleep(1)
            autodeleterunning = False
        else:
            await ctx.send(f'The autodelete command is already running in this server')
```

I want the loop to restart every 100 seconds after the purge is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/#discord-ext-tasks-asyncio-task-helpers) instead of [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/#discord-ext-commands-bot-commands-framework) for these kind of commands.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
import asyncio


@tasks.loop(seconds=100)
async def autopurge(channel):
    message = await channel.send(f'All messages gonna be deleted in 100 seconds')
    await message.pin()
    try:
        await channel.purge(limit=1000)
    except:
        await channel.send("I could not purge messages!")


@client.group(invoke_without_command=True)
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def autopurge(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Please use `autopurge start` to start the loop.")


# Start the loop
@autopurge.command()
async def start(ctx):
    task = autopurge.get_task()
    if task and not task.done():
        await ctx.send("Already running")
        return
    autopurge.start(ctx.channel)


# Stop the loop
@autopurge.command()
async def stop(ctx):
    task = autopurge.get_task()
    if task and not task.done():
        autopurge.stop()
        return
    await ctx.send("Loop was not running")
```

Comment: But its doing a erro
`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Loop' object has no attribute 'is_running'
`

Comment: What the command to stop the look, I already tried alot of things like stop(autopurge)
And I searched alot and didnt find a answer
Can you help me?